# Why i cannot import numba.cuda.random this module?

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I'm tring to import some modules which i have installed before. But errors occur, says no module named 'numba.cuda.random'

```
import math
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing 
import numba as nb
from numba import cuda
import random
import os

from numba.cuda.random import create_xoroshiro128p_states
```

All the first 7 lines work well, but the last line report an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numba.cuda.random'
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the numba, it works!

pip install numba --upgrade